# How to publish nuget package with unmanaged dlls for x64 and x86

Tags: .net, nuget, dllimport

I have a dotnet 5.0 project where I make use of native (unmanaged) libraries through DllImport.
I have different binaries for x64 and x86, and different binaries linux as well.
This totals 10 binaries, 5 per platform architecture (x86 and x64), 3 .dll files and 2 .so files

I have these files conditionally copy to output directory depending on active platform (x86 or x64). This works fine, however I am also trying to package this as a NuGet package.

Now when publishing the NuGet package I need all of these 10 files to be included in the package, and package consumers would need the correct .dll files available. How do I go about this?

This is an example of my current configuration in my .csproj file for copying to output

```xml
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
    <ContentWithTargetPath Include="Binaries\x64\net.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="\build\x64">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <TargetPath>net.dll</TargetPath>
    </ContentWithTargetPath>
    <ContentWithTargetPath Include="Binaries\x64\net.so" Pack="true" PackagePath="\build\64">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <TargetPath>net.so</TargetPath>
    </ContentWithTargetPath>
    <ContentWithTargetPath Include="Binaries\x64\NetModuleWrapper.so" Pack="true" PackagePath="\build\64">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <TargetPath>NetModuleWrapper.so</TargetPath>
    </ContentWithTargetPath>
    <ContentWithTargetPath Include="Binaries\x64\NetModuleWrapper.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="\build\64">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <TargetPath>NetModuleWrapper.dll</TargetPath>
    </ContentWithTargetPath>
    <ContentWithTargetPath Include="Binaries\x64\pthread.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="\build\64">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <TargetPath>pthread.dll</TargetPath>
    </ContentWithTargetPath>
  </ItemGroup>
```

And I have the following as an attempt to get them packaged correctly in the NuGet package

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Binaries\x86\net.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="\runtimes\win10-x86\native">
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Binaries\x86\NetModuleWrapper.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="\runtimes\win10-x86\native">
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Binaries\x86\pthread.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="\runtimes\win10-x86\native">
    </Content>

    <Content Include="Binaries\x86\net.so" Pack="true" PackagePath="\runtimes\linux-x86\native">
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Binaries\x86\NetModuleWrapper.so" Pack="true" PackagePath="\runtimes\linux-x86\native">
    </Content>
    
    <Content Include="Binaries\x64\net.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="\runtimes\win10-x64\native">
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Binaries\x64\NetModuleWrapper.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="\runtimes\win10-x64\native">
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Binaries\x64\pthread.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="\runtimes\win10-x64\native">
    </Content>

    <Content Include="Binaries\x64\net.so" Pack="true" PackagePath="\runtimes\linux-x64\native">
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Binaries\x64\NetModuleWrapper.so" Pack="true" PackagePath="\runtimes\linux-x64\native">
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

The files are included in the package as indicated in the filepath, but the consuming application can not find the .dll files

Comment: Try to add the PackageCopyToOutput property <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>